# How can I change a string in a file in increments ?

Tags: shell

I have the below file :-

```
commit67e255f3c53fe69897dada1cae609a32e
Author:A<a.b@example.com>
Date:WedNov819:40:252017+0530
FileA.properties
commitd46b7275196bd23b02001523a1317e7efaf0
Author:B<b.c@example.com>
Date:WedNov816:20:492017+0530
FileB.properties
commit9598b6ac4e67bfb90f87c0164b06dca97144
Author:C<c.d@example.com>
Date:WedNov813:37:422017+0530
FileC.properties
```

and I want it to change the string commit = commit1 and so on.

I want the below output :-

```
commit1=67e255f3c53fe69897dada1cae609a32e
Author1=A<a.b@example.com>
Date1=WedNov819:40:252017+0530
File1=FileA.properties
commit2=d46b7275196bd23b02001523a1317e7efaf0
Author2=B<b.c@example.com>
Date2=WedNov816:20:492017+0530
File2=FileB.properties
commit3=9598b6ac4e67bfb90f87c0164b06dca97144
Author3=C<c.d@example.com>
Date3=WedNov813:37:422017+0530
File3=FileC.properties
```

Comment: I think you should take a look at https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats. You'll have to customise the o/p to get the indices (1,2,3,4, etc.)

Comment: Are you still looking for a answer?